# SSMS Rolling Average over Day of Week

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Leadership wants to know how Teammates are performing on Mondays & Fridays in comparison to the rest of the work week. Below is a sample temp dbo of a Teammate X's daily performance over a two-month period. Each subsequent Teammate has a different starting point from whence they are measured. I initially looked at using UNBOUNDED PRECEDING in conjunction with the various start dates, but windows functions are not cooperating. Help!

```
CREATE TABLE #RollingAverage
(
    [Date]     DATE PRIMARY KEY
    ,[Value]   INT
);

INSERT INTO #RollingAverage
SELECT '2019-01-02',626
UNION ALL SELECT '2019-01-03',231 UNION ALL SELECT '2019-01-04',572
UNION ALL SELECT '2019-01-07',775 UNION ALL SELECT '2019-01-09',660
UNION ALL SELECT '2019-01-10',662 UNION ALL SELECT '2019-01-11',541
UNION ALL SELECT '2019-01-14',849 UNION ALL SELECT '2019-01-15',632
UNION ALL SELECT '2019-01-16',906 UNION ALL SELECT '2019-01-18',961
UNION ALL SELECT '2019-01-21',501 UNION ALL SELECT '2019-01-24',311
UNION ALL SELECT '2019-01-25',614 UNION ALL SELECT '2019-01-28',296
UNION ALL SELECT '2019-01-29',390 UNION ALL SELECT '2019-01-31',804
UNION ALL SELECT '2019-02-01',928 UNION ALL SELECT '2019-02-05',855
UNION ALL SELECT '2019-02-06',605 UNION ALL SELECT '2019-02-08',283
UNION ALL SELECT '2019-02-12',144 UNION ALL SELECT '2019-02-14',382
UNION ALL SELECT '2019-02-15',862 UNION ALL SELECT '2019-02-18',549
UNION ALL SELECT '2019-02-19',401 UNION ALL SELECT '2019-02-20',515
UNION ALL SELECT '2019-02-21',590 UNION ALL SELECT '2019-02-22',625
UNION ALL SELECT '2019-02-25',304 UNION ALL SELECT '2019-02-26',402
UNION ALL SELECT '2019-02-27',326;
```

`AVG(Value) over (ORDER BY [Date] ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)` did not work

Comment: Define "did not work".    If you got an error, what was the error message?   If you got results, what was wrong with them?

Comment: The error I'm getting is "Incorrect syntax near 'ROWS' "

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to understand, is that your "daily" performance is not daily. A simple solution would be to fill the gaps to be able to effectively count the days.

I filled the gaps using a CTE that generates a calendar table on the fly, but you could use a permanent calendar table if available.

```
WITH 
E(n) AS(
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
cteCalendar(calDate) AS(
    SELECT TOP (61) 
        CAST( DATEADD( DD, 1-ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)), GETDATE()) AS date) AS calDate
    FROM E2
),
cteRollingAverages AS(        
    SELECT ra.[Date], 
        ra.value,
        AVG(Value) over (ORDER BY calDate ROWS BETWEEN 7 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) RollingAverage
    FROM #RollingAverage AS ra
    RIGHT JOIN cteCalendar AS c ON ra.[Date] = c.calDate
)
SELECT *
FROM cteRollingAverages
WHERE [Date] IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY [Date];
```

A different option is to use APPLY. This is not limited by a certain date.

```
SELECT *
FROM #RollingAverage r
CROSS APPLY( SELECT AVG(i.[Value]) AS RollingAvg
            FROM #RollingAverage i
            WHERE i.[Date] BETWEEN DATEADD( DD, -7, r.[Date]) AND r.[Date]) av
ORDER BY [Date];
```

Comment: I see what you are saying. What I don't want is to include NULL or 0 values in the count. Missing dates in the sample set indicate absentee days. I simply want to average performance on active days.

Comment: The query is not including NULL or 0 values. NULLs are omitted by aggregate functions (including the window functions), and we're not adding zeros to include them. However, you need to add the missing dates to keep the number of rows consistent.

Comment: Am I going to have to populate all those vacant days when I get to 6 months' worth of data multiplied by additional Teammates. Is there an easier way to compile this conditional aggregate?

Comment: I added a different option that might serve you better. I suggest that you compare both for performance.

Comment: Thanks, Luis. I feel like the terminology is setting this apart from my end goal. I am not looking for a "moving average" (over last X days), but from an initial starting point going forward, conditionally.

Comment: You will need to add more details on what you need. There's no way to define teammates or what's the start date for them. You should also post expected results based on the sample data that you posted.